# JAVA e Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Imaginem que estamos recebendo um JSON via REST, então para quem usa spring ou jersey, geralmente usa o jackson que deserializa a string json para objeto java automaticamente, isso no início até fiquei impressionado, mas a pouco tempo venho trabalhando com NodeJS, bom o objetivo não é comparar, mas sim, entender por que em java não pode ser igual (que seria muito bom).

Aprendi que preciso criar um DTO ou VO (POJO), que represente o json recebido para que o jackson possa deserializar e me fornecer um objeto JAVA pronto para uso, mas ficar criando DTO depois de ver a naturalidade que isso ocorre com NodeJS, poxa tem me deixado muito irritado... até porque as vezes recebemos json "complexos" com vários objetos dentro de objetos, dentro de arrays, etc...

A pergunta é simples: Existe alguma forma de receber um json e acessar seus atributos sem ter que criar DTOs?

Exemplo:

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "nome": "TESTE",
   "atividades": [
       {
           "id": "1",
           "tarefa": "Fazer tal coisa"
       }
   ]
}
```

Agora gostaria de acessar os atributos, em node eu faria algo assim, detalhe sem DTOs:

```
objeto.id
objeto.nome
```

Já em JAVA eu teria que criar uma DTO para o objeto pai e um outro para o array, para que jackson deserialize, isso é um saco com todo respeito... uma plataforma como JAVA com certeza deve ter algo melhor, acredito que o problema aqui sou eu mesmo que não conheço uma forma, toda ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma diferença significativa entre a framework *Node.js* e *Java* que é o fato de Java ser uma **linguagem fortemente tipada enquanto Node.js (Javascript) não**. A forma de criação e manipulação de objetos são diferentes.

Javascript por exemplo pode consumir um serviço *REST* e fazer parse do resultado para um objeto javascript, fornecendo a automia de usar [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para percorrer as chaves e valores, ou [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) em caso de arrays - isso realmente é maravilhoso.

> A pergunta é simples: Existe alguma forma de receber um json e acessar
>   seus atributos sem ter que criar DTOs?

Como uma alternativa para a sua dúvida, é possível usar o [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) da Google para deserializar um *JSON* para um Objeto *Java* e então acessar as chaves e valores, mas mesmo assim, caso exista objetos aninhados e/ou arrays (que são objetos também) o tratamento não será tão genérico, você terá que informar o que fazer com eles caso queira acessar um subatributo.

### Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String json = "{\"id\": \"1\",\"nome\": \"TESTE\",\"atividades\": [{\"id\": \"1\",\"tarefa\": \"Fazer tal coisa\"}]}";
    Map<String, Object> a = new Gson().fromJson(json, Object.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : a.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
    }

}
```

**Saída:**

```
id => 1
nome => TESTE
atividades => [{id=1, tarefa=Fazer tal coisa}]
```

Comment: Olá Lucas,

Ótima explicação, muito obrigado!!

Acho que por essas e outras razões que NodeJS vem ganhando muito espaço rapidamente, percebo muita naturalidade em programar JS, claro que deve ter seus pontos negativos, mas por enquanto não enxergo muitos motivos para usar JAVA no dia-dia, multi-plataforma já não é mais uma vantagem tão grande assim.

Sou fã do C++ e JAVA quem sabe alguém traga alguma ideia que não conhecemos ainda.

Abração cara valeu mesmo!!!